# Normalizing a Gaussian function

Tags: normal-distribution, normed-spaces

I want to find the normalization constant for the function $f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$.

I start by calculating the norm of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$:
$$ \newcommand{\dx}{\text{d}x}||f||^{2} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right]^{2} \dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-2x^{2}}{2}}\dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$$

However, I know that the answer should be $||f||=\sqrt{2\pi}$, and thus $||f||^{2}=2\pi$.

What am I missing here?..

Answer (score 1):

Normalization ensures $\int f(x)\ dx = 1$, not that the integral of the *square* of the functions equals 1.